# Add a Column with a string value based on other column values R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add one a column called **"Opt-Numbers"** to my data frame with the following values **Opt-CMM** and **Opt-MM** based on **Numbers** column. If the value in **Numbers** column are greater or equal to 4 then it should add Opt-CMM in the same row of that value or if it is less than 4 then add Opt-MM in the same row. I am also showing an example in below df.

Given DF.

| S.NO | Numbers |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | 2 |
| P2 | 5 |
| P3 | 2 |
| P4 | 2 |
| P5 | 3 |
| P6 | 4 |

**Required DF**

| S.NO | Numbers | Opt-Numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 2 | Opt-MM |
| P2 | 5 | Opt-CMM |
| P3 | 2 | Opt-MM |
| P4 | 2 | Opt-MM |
| P5 | 3 | Opt-MM |
| P6 | 4 | Opt-CMM |

Comment: Try `DF$\`Opt-Numbers\` <- ifelse(DF$Numbers >= 4, "Opt-CMM", "Opt-MM"))`

Comment: @stefan It works. Kindly can you add your answer ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with dplyr and case_when ()

```
library(dplyr)
```

#example data

```
data <- structure(list(S.NO = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6"), Numbers = c(2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

create new column with filters

```
data <- data %>%
          mutate(Opt-Numbers = case_when(
                    Numbers >= 4 ~ "Opt-CMM",
                    Numbers < 4 ~ "Opt-MM"
          ))

data
```